# Python XML SOAP Request Returning 400 But Postman Returns 200

Tags: python-3.x, xml, soap, python-requests

I'm trying to query a SOAP API using requests, and I am able to get this to work in Postman just fine.
However, when I try to make my request using requests in Python, I keep getting a 400 response.

This is my code so far:

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.wsa import WsAddressingPlugin
import contextlib
import OpenSSL.crypto
import os
import requests
import ssl
import tempfile
import certifi
import http.client
from OpenSSL import crypto
from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature
import xmlsec
import pprint
from json import dumps


headers = {'content-type':'application/soap+xml','action':'http://Blah/IBlah/EntitySearch'}
body = """
xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:hsd="http://Blah">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://Blah/IBlah/EntitySearch</wsa:Action><wsa:To>https://blahblahblah:120/HSD.ProxyService/Blah.svc?wsdl</wsa:To></soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <hsd:EntitySearch>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <hsd:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hsd:EntityId>100000</hsd:EntityId>
         </hsd:request>    
      </hsd:EntitySearch>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>""".encode('utf-8')

r = requests.post('https://blahblahblah:120/Blah.ProxyService/Blah.svc?wsdl',cert=('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\llama_cert.pem', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\llama.key'),data=body,headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

The SOAP XML does work in Postman, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and getting the 400 response. I switched from POST to GET and took out the data and the headers, and I was able to get a 200 response back from that.
I did do this in Zeep as well, but Zeep is requiring me to put in two request fields and I really need to get my program to work with one.

I'm open to any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: A good diagnostic step is to put a HTTP proxy between your Python script and the server to see the exact content of your request. Burp Suite Community is a popular example. What does the 400 response say?

Comment: Hi @Thomas ! I don't know how to do that, but if you can point me in the right direction, that would be super helpful! When I do print out the content, I just get b'', and if I just print the response, I get <Response [400]>

Comment: Sure, the Burp Suite documentation has info on the proxy [here](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/getting-started). But I'm actually reminded of the Python debugging server, now that I think about it. If you run the code with a debugger and add a breakpoint right after the POST request, you can see details about the request. For now, try printing: `r.request`, `r.reason`, `r.raw`, and `r` itself).

Comment: if you are using `zeep` there is no need to handle the `xml`, `zeep` will do it for you.

Comment: Hi @Thomas! So I ran the r.request, and I got <PreparedRequest [POST]>. r.reason returned Bad Request, r.raw returned <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x0000024D410A0FA0>, and r returns <Response [400]>. I am running this through Visual Studio, so I am not sure if that makes any difference or not. @Tarique I do have a program that works using zeep, but it is requiring two fields to send a message and I really need just one so that is why I'm trying to use the XML to make my request.

Comment: @Thomas I did run a debugger just now, and the only thing that I notice is that body has a b in front of it, which is making me think that it is a byte instead of what I have encoded for in my code to be a utf-8.

Comment: Could be a header. Anything for `r.content`? I think the proxy would be a good guaranteed bet on this because you could directly compare the requests @Perdue if the debugging here doesn't provide an answer

Answer (score 2):

Even if the question is 2 years old I think it is still valid. I faced this exact same error. Initially, I had the same request header as yours  and I changed it to;

```
***headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
'SOAPAction': 'Retrieve'
}.***
```

It solved my error and I started to get 200 OK response from my client.
I hope it helps

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76235624/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where a Postman SOAP request always returned 200 and when I tried to do it in Python with the requests library it returned 500, saying I didn't provide a input parameter, as soon as I added a SOAPAction header.

My SOAPAction header in Postman was the following: `ReadMultiple`

When trying the exact same in Python, it didn't work. Now I changed it to `urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/nameoftheservice:ReadMultiple` and it works.

What is also worth trying is removing all line breaks, if you formatted your payload.

Answer (score 0):

You need check post data encode,
encode must equal post header encode

```
if headers = {'content-type':'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'}

soap_xml_utf8 = soap_xml.encode("utf-8")

request post data = soap_xml_utf8
```